# Question based on finer and coarser topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am trying exercise 1.2 (question 12) of C. Wayne Patty Foundations of Topology.

I am struck on it.

> Question is-> No. 12 [image]

I am unable to think how such a space in (1) must exist as union of topology is not always a topology. ( I could only think of Union of these topologies but it's not a topology.

Also, can someone please give some hint for (2) . It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant topology $\mathscr{T}$ is the set of intersections of open sets in the topologies, i.e. $S$ is open if and only if it can be expressed as $\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} S_\alpha$ where $S_\alpha \in \mathscr{T}_\alpha$.

For part (2), suppose $\mathscr{T}'$ that is finer than all $\mathscr{T}_\alpha$. Then $\mathscr{T}'$ contains all open sets in all $\mathscr{T}_\alpha$, so for any collection of open sets $\{S_\alpha\}$ where each $S_\alpha \in \mathscr{T}_\alpha$ (i.e. any collection of open sets, one from each topology), we know that each $S_\alpha$ is also in $\mathscr{T}$, and hence their intersection is open in $\mathscr{T}$.

Hence all elements of $\mathscr{T}$ are elements of $\mathscr{T}'$, and so $\mathscr{T}$ is coarser than $\mathscr{T}'$.

Comment: The intersection is not finer than all the other topologies.

Comment: For an open set $S_1 \in \mathscr{T_1}$, $S_1$ can be written as the union of $\bigcup_{S_\alpha \in \mathscr{T_\alpha}, \alpha \neq 1}\cap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} S_\alpha$, and hence $\mathscr{T_1}$ is a subset of the intersection topology, which means it's finer, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @hdighfan can you please give a detailed answer on (2) I cannot think about it.

Comment: @DxdxDxdx I'll edit in an answer to (2) now.

Comment: @hdighfancan you please edit the mistake you did in part (1) answer as it's not clear what you are implying.

Comment: @MadMax Ah, that's not what I meant by intersection; I've clarified my answer now.

Comment: @DxdxDxdx I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: @hdighfan how would topology by defined if  I want T to be coarser than $ T_{\alpha} $  ? instead of finer as asked in this question. Can you please give hint.

Comment: @hdighfan can you please reply to above question asked in previous comment?

Comment: Assuming you swap every instance of "coarser" with "finer" and vice versa, the answer should be the intersection of all $\mathscr T _\alpha$. It's easy to see that this is a topology, and any topology coarser than all $\mathscr T _\alpha$ must be contained within their intersection and so the intersection is finer.

Comment: (@user795826 just dropping a notification here because I forgot to add one earlier)

Answer (score 1):

Proceeding stepwise,

Step 1. let us take the *union* of all the topologies in your collection, let's call this union $\mathscr{S}$;

Step 2.  construct the collection of all the topologies on your set $X$ each of which contains as a subset the collection $\mathscr{S}$ in Step 1; of course the power set $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is one such topology so that this collection of topologies is non-empty;

and,

Step 3. Take the *intersection* of all the topologies in the collection constructed in Step 2; this intersection is of course a topology on set $X$.

Finally, check that the topology constructed in Step 3 has your desired properties.

Please feel free to ask for clarification should you get stuck at any  point in the foregoing solution.